# How to catch and validate the input date type?

Tags: php, html

I am trying to create a PHP validation form. I have two problems here:

1. Validate the email input
2. Validate the date input

For some reason it doesn't catch these two. Here's my form.php

```
<div class="form_reg">
    <h2>Registration Form</h2>
    <form action="registration_process.php" method="post">
        <p><label for="email">Email:</label>
        <input type="email" name="email" value=""/></p>

        <p><label for="first_name">First Name:</label>
        <input type="text" name="first_name" value=""/></p>

        <p><label for="last_name">Last Name:</label>
        <input type="text" name="last_name" value=""/></p>

        <p><label for="password">Password:</label>
        <input type="password" name="password" value=""/></p>

        <p><label for="confirm_password">Confirm Password:</label>
        <input type="password" name="confirm_password" value=""/></p>

        <p><label for="date">Birth Date:</label>
        <input type="date" name="date" value=""/></p>

        <input type="submit"/>
    </form>
```

Here's my validate.php:

```
session_start();
$errors = array();
//empty array to collect errors

if(empty($_POST['email']) AND !filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false)
{
    $errors[] = "email cannot be blank";
}

if(empty($_POST['first_name']))
{
    $errors[] = "First Name cannot be blank";
} 

if(empty($_POST['last_name']))
{
    $errors[] = "Last Name cannot be blank";
}   

if(empty($_POST['password']))
{
    $errors[] = "Password cannot be blank";
} 

if(empty($_POST['confirm_password']) AND $_POST['password'] == $_POST['confirm_password'])
{
    $errors[] = "Please enter matching password";
} 

if(empty($_POST['confirm_password']) AND $_POST['password'] == $_POST['confirm_password'])
{
    $errors[] = "Please enter matching password";
} 

if(isset($_POST['date']) && strtotime($_POST['date']))
{
    $errors[] = "Birth Date cannot be blank";
} 

if(!empty($errors))
{
    //if there are errors, assign the session variable!
    $_SESSION['errors'] = $errors;
    //redirect your user back using header('location: ')
    header('Location: registration_page.php');
}
else
{
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
    $last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $birth_date = $_POST['date'];
    //redirect your user to the next part of the site!
}
?>
```

Any idea?

Comment: `if(empty($_POST['email']) OR filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false)`  you should use `OR` and remove the `!` since you are checking already for false on `=== false`

Comment: `if(!isset($_POST['date']) || !strtotime($_POST['date']))` on the date condition too

Comment: Your logic is just screwed up.

Comment: if(empty($_POST['email']) OR filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false) even if I set this one still getting me an error. I am inserting my corect email and its returning the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might be you should try like this also. First, check either email is blank or not. If not blank, check either it is in correct format:

```
 if(empty($_POST['email']))
 {
     $errors[] = "email cannot be blank";

 }else if(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
 {
        $errors[] = "invalid email";
 }
```

and this also:

```
 if(!isset($_POST['date']){
     $errors[] = "date is blank";
 }else if(!strtotime($_POST['date'])){
     $errors[] = "invalid date";
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is just a smidge off.

For the email, try:

```
if(empty($_POST['email']))
 {
     // if no email was entered
     $errors[] = "email cannot be blank";
 } 
else if (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false) 
 {
     // email was entered, but was invalid
     $errors[] = "please enter a valid email";
 }
```

You want to trigger this if block if `$_POST['email']` is blank, *or* if it isn't a valid email address. Since you're checking the output of the `filter_var()` function, you want to check whether it *is equal* to `false`.

For the date, try:

```
if(!isset($_POST['date']))
 {
     // if no date was entered
     $errors[] = "Birth Date cannot be blank";
 } 
else if (strtotime($_POST['date']) === false) 
 {
     // date was entered, but was invalid
     $errors[] = "please enter a valid date";
 }
```

Since you want to trigger the date error if a) the date is left blank, or b) it's not a valid date, this if block should run only if `$_POST['date']` is *not* set, or if `strtotime()` returns false.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly your code for email is saying if the email is NOT empty then ignore the email format checking. This I do not think is what you wanted. Additionally you have a double negative using !filter_var and then === false.

I believe you wanted something like: (I separated them onto different lines so you can see the flow better)

```
     if( empty($_POST['email']) OR 
     ( filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false )  ) {
         $errors[] = "email is blank or incorrectly formatted";
     }
```

Secondly your Date is doing a similar thing, I believe you want something like below again:

```
   if( isset($_POST['date']) OR 
   !strtotime($_POST['date'])) {
        $errors[] = "Birth Date must be a valid date";
   }
```

*NOTE: strtotime will return -1 not false on version previous to PHP 5.1.0, you are most likely on a version higher then that thou.*

**EDIT: Notice I change the $email to $_POST['email'] as you never set $email anywhere in the code you showed.**